# Is there a term for not identifying with your current age?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, psychology, pop-culture

"Transgender" refers to someone who doesn't identify with their birth gender. "Transracial" refers to someone who doesn't identify with their birth race.

Is there a term for someone who doesn't identify with their current age? For example, if someone is 50 years old, but feels a like they are 30?

Perhaps something like "Transaged"?
Is there a generally accepted term for this?

Comment: [Poe's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe%27s_law).

Comment: To use the words "doesn't identify with their current age" misleads. The nearest suggestions that the answerers have come up with relate to people who act in a way characteristic not of people their own age but of older people ("mature for their years", "young fogey") or younger ("young at heart"). Such people don't deny their true age or identify with another age. Nobody does. This does not parallel "transgender", which describes people who have changed their gender.

Comment: Are you sure you want to go with *transaged*? After all, a hermit who goes up the mountain to meditate and experiences profound enlightenment could be said to have been transaged. :)

Comment: I don't much agree with those negative definitions. And age and those identifications are not related.

Answer (score 19):

No, *Mature for their age* and *Young at heart* are about the best you'll get.

Comment: "Mature for their age" refers to a characteristic. You wouldn't say to a friend, "He's feminine for his gender" in order to tell your friend that the person *identifies* as feminine.

Comment: Gender consists of discrete values. Age is continuous. That's the difference.

Comment: I would agree with you on that (though many people wouldn't); but either way, I don't see how that is related to the distinction between a characteristic and the way a person identifies

Answer (score 14):

maybe [**age dysphoria**](https://aboutabdl.weebly.com/age-dysphoria.html)

> Typical Presentation:
>   1. An enduring concept of self that is younger than one’s chronological age.
>   2. Intense dissatisfaction with adult characteristics
>   3. Persistent fantasies of being younger
>   4. Persistent role-playing (regression) as being younger than one’s chronological age.

Comment: So is that the medical term for what is popularly known as Peter Pan Syndrome? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puer_aeternus#Peter_Pan_syndrome

Comment: Do you have any original content to contribute? Answers should consist mostly of original content, and use links and citations only to support those arguments.

Comment: @tchrist What? Link-only answers are bad, but he put the relevant excerpt here, which is good. Unless english.SE is way different than SO, this is a perfectly fine answer.

Comment: @m69 PP is a pop variant. This answer is a subset of gender dysmorphias ... just now emerging with gender issues.

Comment: @GregSchmit Please see this guidance from Stack Exchange management regarding [***Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity***](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085).

Answer (score 5):

I think that “transaged” (sometimes hyphenated: “trans-aged”) is the perfect word to describe this since that’s the word I’m seeing used. It’s also perfectly clear to anyone who hasn’t heard it before, since it parallels “transgender”. For example it is used here:

> But the president is stone-silent on the rights of the trans-aged: individuals whose age does not align with the date they were assigned at birth.
>   <sub>[The Trans-Aged Deserve Equal Rights, Too](http://thefederalist.com/2015/12/10/the-trans-aged-deserve-equal-rights-too/)</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81081/discussion-on-answer-by-laurel-is-there-a-term-for-not-identifying-with-your-cur).

Comment: Im not sure thats a good example. The Federalist is a highly conservative far right newspaper, and that article uses the term in a sarcastic, mocking tone.

Answer (score 1):

*Late bloomer* and *early bloomer* come to mind, though these seem focused more on accomplishments than on feelings.

[Merriam-Webster says a *late bloomer*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/late%20bloomer) is:

> *US*
> : someone who becomes successful, attractive, etc., at a later time in life than other people
>
> - She was a *late bloomer* as a writer.

Answer (score 1):

Another good one is "transchrono", which is used on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/KotakuInAction/comments/5f0jlq/college_caps_men_on_its_bbc_quiz_show_team/dah6vv9/?utm_content=permalink&utm_medium=front&utm_source=reddit&utm_name=KotakuInAction), and [blogs](http://www.strike-the-root.com/sooner-or-later), though usually in a sarcastic way.

There is even a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yv5Eqv8Nrpw) explaining the term and the concept behind it (basically the same thing as transgender, but for age)

Comment: Does this term appear in any curated dictionary? To me is sounds like a fancy word for a time-traveller.

Comment: Sound pejorative.